# Google Cloud Vision - Data Set cannot be split into train, validation, test data

Tags: google-cloud-platform, object-detection, google-vision

I am trying to build an object detection model using Google Cloud Vision. The model should draw bounding boxes around rice

**What I have done so far:**

1. I have imported an image set of 15 images
2. I have used the Google Cloud tool to draw ~550 bounding boxes in 10 images

[image: This is the data set I created. 10 labelled images with ~550 bounding boxes drawn around grains of rice]

**Where I am stuck:**
I have built models before, and the data set was automatically split into train, validation and test set. This time however, **Google Cloud** is not splitting the data set.

[image: I cannot start training, because all data is used for training, rather than splitting into test, validation and training]

**What I have tried:**

1. Downloading the .csv with the labeled data and reimporting it into Google Cloud
2. Adding more labels beyond the one label I have right now
3. Deleting and recreating the data set

***How can I get Google Cloud to split the data set?***

Comment: As far as I know, there's no way for doing this directly on GCP, you would need to split the data set using a different tool

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that *Google Cloud Platform* determined your train, test and validation sets **when you uploaded** your images. Your test and validation images are likely your last 5 images which are not available for training if you have not labeled them yet. If you label all of your images or remove those from the dataset you should be able to train. [See this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66083818/2202359) for more info.

You can verify this by clicking the `Export Data` option and downloading a CSV of your dataset: you can see that data set categories are already defined, even for images that have not yet been labeled yet.